# Frama-C Prove While Loop with "/*@ ensures"

Tags: c, loops, verification, frama-c, acsl

I am a newbie at Frama-C and I am trying to validate a C code. The code is very basic but somehow I can not validate it.

In summary, I am trying to prove If that function or loop has ever run. For that, I give a variable a value (4) in the beginning. In the function, I change the value to "5", and I try to ensure that the variable 5 at the end.

The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x=4;
/*@
ensures x ==5;
*/
int abs(int val){

    int accept=0;
    int count=3;
    /*@
    loop invariant 0 <= count <= \at(count, Pre);
    loop assigns accept,x,count; 
    loop variant count;
    */
    while (count !=0){
        x=5;
        accept =1;
        count--;
    }
    return x;
 }
```

I give the command to CLI as "frama-c-gui -wp -rte testp4.c" to start frama-c.

As result:
[Frama-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iKZJ.png)

But the "*@ ensures x ≡ 5; */" is still **unknown**.

Is there anyone can help me about this ? If I take `"x=5;"` to outside of the while loop ( before return) It validates the `/*@ ensures x ==5; */`

Thanks in advance to everyone who contributed!

Comment: I notice that you have `x ≡ 5` in the link, but `x == 5` here. Also `≤` vs `<=`.

Comment: Isn't your `"x=5"` optimized out maybe? Did you compile with `-O0`?

Comment: You should add loop invariant that if count is nonzero then x becomes 5. `\at(count, Pre) != 0 => \at(x, Post) == 5`

Comment: @tstanisl I tried your answer as:

int x=4;
/*@
ensures x ==5;
*/
int abs(int val){

    int accept=0;
    int count=3;
    /*@
    loop invariant \at(count, Pre) != 0 => \at(x, Post) == 5;   
    loop assigns accept,x,count; 
    loop variant count;
    */
    while (count !=0){
        x=5;
        accept =1;
        count--;
    }
    return x;
 }


But the frama-c responds as like below and do not starts frama-c GUI.
""[kernel] user error: Assignment operators not allowed in annotations."" 

Did I apply or understand something wrong ?

Comment: Oops replace `=>` with `==>`

Comment: @tstanisl
/*@
    loop invariant \at(count, Pre) != 0 ==> \at(x, Post) == 5;
    loop assigns accept,x,count; 
    loop variant count;
 */

   Like this?   Frama-c fails as: [kernel] user error: logic label `Post' not found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the problems here are related to the use of builtin labels. Here are the labels that we need here:

- Pre: the state in precondition
- Post: the state in postcondition
- LoopEntry: the state when starting the loop
- Here: the state at the program point where it is used

First things first. I do not known which version of Frama-C you are using but I'd suggest updating ;) . You would have the following error message to prevent a mistake:

```
[kernel:annot-error] file.c:11: Warning: 
  unbound logic variable count. Ignoring loop annotation
```

Why? Because you are talking about `count` in precondition when it does not exist. Note that in old versions of Frama-C, WP might be OK with this because the pre-state and the initialization of local variables was merged in some cases.

What we want is probably something like "the current value of `count` is somewhere between 0 and the value it had when we started the loop", thus:

```
loop invariant 0 <= count <= \at(count, LoopEntry);
which is:
loop invariant 0 <= \at(count, Here) <= \at(count, LoopEntry);
```

Now that we have this (proven) invariant, we want to link the behavior of the loop with the postcondition (currenty, our loop invariant does not say anything about `x` and WP does not use the body of the loop out of it. That means that we need another invariant that is "when `count` does not equal to its value when starting the loop, `x` is 5`".

Thus:

```
loop invariant count != \at(count, LoopEntry) ==> x == 5 ;
```

Which allows to have the program entirely proved :) . Final annotated program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int x=4;
/*@
  ensures x ==5;
*/
int abs(int val){

  int accept=0;
  int count=3;
  /*@
    loop invariant 0 <= count <= \at(count, LoopEntry);
    loop invariant count != \at(count, LoopEntry) ==> x == 5 ;
    loop assigns accept,x,count; 
    loop variant count;
  */
  while (count !=0){
    x=5;
    accept =1;
    count--;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Some words about why `\at(count, Pre) != 0 ==> \at(x, Post) == 5` (in the comments) does not work:

- `\at(count, Pre)` is the value of `count` in precondition *of the function* and `\at(count, Post)` is the value of `count` in postcondition *of the function*. Thus, not what we need here.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the answer.

I added two lines as 
`loop invariant 0 <= \at(count, Here) <= \at(count, LoopEntry);`, and
`loop invariant count != \at(count, LoopEntry) ==> x == 5 ;`.

When the x=5 in the while loop, all is good and "ensures x==5" is valid. But when I set x=4 in the loop, the ensure is still VALID **but under hypothesis**. This is it? Or does it still needs improving?

Comment: If you change your assignment in the loop, the `loop invariant` cannot be proved anymore: `x` is not `5` but `4`. Thus, WP fails to prove it. Then, recall that when WP creates the verification condition for the `ensures`, it does not use the body of the loop, just the `loop invariant`, thus it can prove the property. But, since the `loop invariant` is not proved (and the proof of the `ensures` depends on it), it only says that it is valid provided that someone succeeds in proving the `loop invariant` (which will not happen here).